# jscrollpane scrolltobottom but pause with mouseover on scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

i have finished this code off but im stuck on teh last thing i have to do, when a item is added it auto scrolls to the bottom which is great but what i cannot work out how to do and im sure its simple is when i use the scroll bar i want to stop it jumping to the bottom until i stop using the scroll bar.

you will see in the example ive provided if you click on scrollbar and drag up it keeps jumping down when it adds a new item, i just need to pause that until i stop using the scroll bar if that makes sense.

it uses api.scrollToBottom(); to scroll to the bottom once the new item is added which is correct, but unsure on the condition for mouseover etc... to stop that when those are the conditions.

Hope someone can help me on this, many thanks in advance! :)

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GT7sV/2/

JS

```
var settings = {
        showArrows: true,
        verticalArrowPositions: 'os',
        horizontalArrowPositions: 'os',
        animateScroll: true
    };
    var pane = jQuery('.scroll-pane');
    pane.jScrollPane(settings);
    var api = pane.data('jsp');
    var i = 1;

    api.scrollToBottom();

    setInterval(
        function()
        {
            api.getContentPane().append("<li>testing this new item</li>").children(':last').hide().fadeIn(1000);
            api.reinitialise();
            api.scrollToBottom();
        },
        1000
    );

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is ok for you but you could try it in different direction. You could load new rows when user scrolls to the bottom:

```
conversationHeadersScrollPane = $('.scroll-pane').bind(
        'jsp-scroll-y',
        function(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom) {
            if (isAtBottom) {
                //add new rows for example with ajax call
            }
});
```

edit: there is a function getPercentScrolledY()
so you could before calling scrollToBottom check if user is for example bellow 90%, if not let him read while he scrolls on his own to the bottom.